# How to display dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, kaggle

I am doing the Titanic problem in Kaggle and I have problems displaying the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

titanic = pd.read_csv("input/train.csv")
titanic.head()
```

This should display the `train.csv` but it doesn't. Do you know why?

Comment: Have you tried using `print(titanic.head())` first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you are using the REPL in Sublime Text or just running the program, you can display a dataframe called *titanic* as:

```
# prints first 5 rows in dataframe format
print(titanic.head())

# prints all rows in dataframe format
print(titanic)
```

If you want to display the data frame in CSV format, you need to convert it to CSV first using the *to_csv* function:

```
# prints first 5 rows in CSV format
print(titanic.head().to_csv())

# prints all rows in CSV format
print(titanic.to_csv())
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you executing this from REPL prompt or as a script? If in REPL, it should print in prompt or if through script, try this.
`df.head().to_csv(sys.stdout)`.

The `to_csv(..)` method takes a filepath or buffer. With this, you are redirecting output to `stdout`. Please ensure to import `sys` module.